# Calculating number of characters excluding whitespace - python

Tags: python, regex, string, whitespace

Which is a faster way to calculate number of characters without whitespaces?
which is more pythonic?

```
def sent_length(sentence):
  return sum(1 for c in sentence if c != ' ')
```

or

```
def sent_length(sentence):
  return len(sentence.replace(" ", ""))
```

or

```
import re 
pattern = re.compile(r'\s+')

def sent_length(sentence):
  return len(re.sub(pattern, '', sentence))
```

Comment: Faster, you can easily test. Pythonic, no answer, they are different approaches.. I would go with the second, the simplest.

Comment: `len("".join(s.split()))` would be another way

Comment: When you say `whitespaces` do you mean space ` ` or any whitespace ` \t\r`, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get timings from `python -m timeit`:

```
[matt tmp] python -m timeit "sum(1 for c in 'blah blah blah' if c != ' ')"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.96 usec per loop
[matt benchmark] python -m timeit -s "import re; pattern = re.compile(r'\s+')" "len(pattern.sub('', 'blah blah blah'))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.2 usec per loop
[matt tmp] python -m timeit "len(''.join('blah blah blah'.split()))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.785 usec per loop
[matt tmp] python -m timeit "len('blah blah blah'.replace(' ', ''))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.437 usec per loop
[matt tmp] python -m timeit "len('blah blah blah') - 'blah blah blah'.count(' ')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.384 usec per loop
```

This will help you determine what is the quickest. More pythonic? I'd go with the fastest as performance is *always* important.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of faster you can test that yourself.

```
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.now()
# some method
end = datetime.now()
diff = end-start
```

In terms of what is more pythonic, I don't believe any of them are more `pythonic`. They are each a valid implementation that most people would accept. It's just a slightly different approach. In general regular expressions will take slightly longer to run.

Comment: `timeit` is a much better way of doing the performance - it does multiple iterations.

Comment: Never knew that, thanks for the info. Normally when I test I just make a unit test of the diff times and average them myself. +1

Comment: you can use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) as a library interface. It'll do all of the averaging for you. Which is great for repeatable benchmark unit tests ;)